# I want to open a blank window using Python without using Tkinter or an equivalent API. How could I do that?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Basically, I'm playing around with the idea of making an alternative to tkinter and am wondering if there's a good lower-level library I could use to write code to open up a blank window, since that might be a good first step. Any ideas on what libraries might be useful for this problem?

Comment: Good alternatives to tkinter already exists like Qt

Comment: What do you mean with "lower-level"? There's lots of GUI toolkits available other than tkinter: pyqt, wxpython, pygtk, and kivy come to mind. Tkinter does not depend on them and they don't depend on tkinter, so I would not call them "lower-level".

Comment: @Novel: I think tho OP is asking about something like xlib.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'll check that out. The answer below about ctypes looks promising as well. And yeah I think you understand what I'm going for. I know there are good alternatives to tkinter, I just wanted to take a stab at making one of my own from scratch, as trivial as the problem might sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Your message", "Your title", 1)
```

This solution will only work for windows OS